# Approximating intersection of regular closed sets with another regular closed set

Tags: general-topology

Consider the Euclidean topology over $\mathbb{R}$. Consider subsets of the unit interval $[0,1]$.

If $A$ and $B$ are regular closed sets, then $C = A\cap B$ is a closed set that may or may not be regular. For instance, $A=[0,0.5]$ and $B=[0.5,1]$ intersect to give $\{0.5\}$, which is not a regular closed set. However, $A = [0,0.6]$ and $B=[0.4,1]$ intersect to give $[0.4,0.6]$, which is a regular closed set.

Is it the case that there exists a regular closed set $D$ such that the Lebesgue measure ($\mu$) of the symmetric difference of $C$ and $D$ denoted as $ C \Delta D$ is zero, i.e., $\mu(C \Delta D)=0$? If this is true, then how can we prove it. I describe my attempt below. Also, does this claim generalize to $\mathbb{R}^d$ as well?

We start with $A$ and $B$ as regular closed sets. Say we can write each of them as union of disjoint intervals as follows $A = \cup_i A_i$  and $B = \cup_j B_j$.   The intersection $C=A\cap B$ will be $\cup_{i,j} A_i \cap B_j$. Each set $A_i \cap B_j$ will also be an interval. Some of these sets  $A_i \cap B_j$ may have interval of length >0 and in other cases they may correspond to singletons, which have length=0. In this case, we can define $D$ as union of intervals $A_i \cap B_j$ of positive length.